# Grafana 8 sort legend

Tags: sorting, grafana, influxdb

Before grafana 8 (i'm using it in combination with influxdb) it was possible to sort legend values, like this:

[image]

Starting from version 8 in new charts I don't see such option:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this option on version 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the new "Timeseries" Graph can't do it (yet?).
However you can select "Graph (old)" which still has this functionality.

[image: Select Graph(old) as visualization]

Comment: According to their support form, this feature should be available in 8.2 https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-8-legend-sort/49566/3. Also, this issue is currently part of the 8.2 milestone within GitHub https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/35429

Comment: It is possible for "Time Series" now.